# Using an XP batch file to import a p12 certificate into the Certificates (Local Computer) \personal store

Tags: windows, batch-file, certificate

I'm trying to use a windows XP batch file to automate importing .p12 certificates into what the MMC "Certificates" snap-in calls 
    Certificates (Local Computer) \Personal\Certificates

certmgr.msc might be the right tool for this purpose, but I have tried

```
a:\certmgr.msc /add /c /s /r localMachine a:\<certname>.p12

importpfx -f a:\certs\<certname>.* -p <cert pw> -t MACHINE -s My
```

And a few others without success. Usually, the MMC just opens with the certificates snap in. I've not seen any certs actually moved or imported anywhere as a result.

I've also tried the cert path\name without the environmental variable and wild card, but the certs I get may or may not simply be the workstation name.p12..

Any suggestions?

-Clay

Comment: I am also confronting this problem. waiting for possible answers~~~

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2.
I used the below command in my batch file:

```
certutil -f -sid 22 -p [Password1] -importpfx "My"  "%~dp0\whatever.pfx" NoRoot

-sid WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE -- Numeric SID
22 -- "Local System", 23 -- "Network Service", 24 -- "Local Service"
```